# Signed angle difference without conditions

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms, angle

I've got two angles in $0 \leqslant a < 360$ and I need to find the signed difference between them which should be $-180 < \Delta < 180$.
Is there a way to calculate the difference with without conditions like:

```
delta = targetAngle - myAngle;
if (delta < 0)  
{  
    delta = delta + 180;  
}  
else  
{  
    if (delta > 180)  
    {  
        delta = delta - 360;  
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that's C code and the variables are integers, the following will give a $\Delta \in [-180, 180)$:

```
    delta = (targetAngle - myAngle + 540) % 360 - 180;
```

If the variables are floating-point, you need to replace `%` with `fmod`, but performance-wise it becomes wasteful vs. just checking the ranges as you had it.

---

[EDIT] Short explanation: `targetAngle - myAngle + 540` calculates `targetAngle - myAngle + 180` and adds `360` to ensure it's a positive number, since compilers can be finicky about `%` modulus with negative numbers. Then `% 360` normalizes the difference to [0, 360). And finally the `- 180` subtracts the `180` added at the first step, and shifts the range to [-180, 180).

Comment: That doesn't seem right. If the two input angles are _equal_ this will produce a "difference" of $-180^\circ$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Edited your first version and it's working fine for me: delta = -((targetAngle - myAngle + 180) % 360 - 180)

Comment: @LaTravavax I edited a short explanation at the end of the answer. See the caveat about `%` with negative numbers.

Comment: I guess the game engine I am working on handles the modulus sign using the dividend so In order to not write a custom modulus function I simply negated the result to get the proper AngleDifference. For instance, it was giving positive results anticlockwise and negative ones clockwise. Thank you very much though, you helped me a lot :)